# How to create a game loop using RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm new to reactive programming with RxJS and want to build a simple game as a way of getting to grips with the library.

Having looked through the documentation I've not come across a clear example on how best to implement a game loop (see below) using Observables.

Can someone provide a solution, or if not a suitable use case, an explanation on why.

```
function gameLoop() {
    // emit tick event

    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Scheduler } from "rxjs/Scheduler";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";
import "rxjs/add/operator/repeat";

Observable
  .of(null, Scheduler.animationFrame)
  .do(() => {})
  .repeat()
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks @cartant I've expanded upon this suggestion to create a game loop with start / stop functionality: https://github.com/garethwhittaker/rxjs-animation-loop

Answer (score 1):

As of RxJs >= 5.5 you do it the following way:

```
import { animationFrameScheduler, of } from 'rxjs';
import { repeat, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

of(null, animationFrameScheduler)
    .pipe(
        tap(() => {
            gameLoop()
        }),
        repeat(),
    )
    .subscribe();
```